# How to deserialize JSON?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize

I have an issue which I've been struggling with today. The JSON is returned back to me with a project Id as the key, this Project Id is dynamically generated and due to this I have not been able to come up with a way to deserialize this response. Any suggestions?

```
{  
   "success":true,
   "numRows":5,
   "data":{  
      "23000079":{  
         "projectId":"23000079",
         "name":"Mcdonalds",
         "departmentId":"9383",
         "responsibleUserId":"7444434"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There's always https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a `Map` as part of the data structure you deserialize to account for the dynamic keys. This allows you to avoid hard-coding the keys as part of your defined structure, which you couldn't do here anyway because they're numeric.

```
public class Response {
    public class Project {
        String projectId;
        String name;
        String departmentId;
        String responsibleUserId;
    }
    Boolean success;
    Integer numRows;
    Map<String, Project> data;
}
```

This structure works to deserialize the JSON you've shown here in a typed way:

```
JSON.deserialize(myJSON, Response.class));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time out of your day to explain this, really appreciate it. This solved my issue.